# Excel function like Python's "in" operator?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to make a cell in excel check all of the cells in a column for a certain group of numbers and then display a value based on those cells. Is there any way I can do this?

EDIT: Here's a simplified spreadsheet that shows what I'm trying to do:

[image: http://i373.photobucket.com/albums/oo178/TSNAKE617/StackOverflow.png]
(My reputation isn't high enough to post images yet.)

I want to check the cells in column B for "1,4,7,10" Then put the sum of the corresponding C cells into E2.

Comment: What have you tried and do you have an example of the data you're trying to match?

Comment: full match or partial match? worksheet function or code/vba-driven? what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Could you show us an example and let us know what you've tried?  I'm not sure what you are wanting exactly.  But based off what you asked:

Try the `find(find_text, within_text, start_num)` function.  Copy and paste that down the entire column and you should get the results out to the side.  For example:

```
   A        B        
1  ABC      =if(iserr(find("A", A1)), "NOT found", "FOUND")
2  XYZ      =if(iserr(find("A", A2)), "NOT found", "FOUND")
```

Would give (in B1, B2)

```
FOUND
NOT found
```

You could also use

`if(iserr(find(...)), 0, 1)`

At the end of your column you could do a `=sum()` and you'd get the number of rows that contain the string you are looking for.

Comment: @Tyson I saw your update (I'd comment but can't due to rep I suppose).  In column E2, can you tell me what your formula is or how you would determine it?  It sounds like you could be saying to add put C2 in E2 if 1 exists in the B2 answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a full-match on the string `1,4,7,10` you can probably use `SUMPRODUCT`

`E2` = `=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$B$6="1,4,7,10"),--($C$2:$C$6))`

It worked for my example, but I might have gotten it wrong!

Cant really explain whats going on in the formula, but if you evaluate it in excel and watch how it calculates it you should get an idea!